# How to generate thumbnail and file name from input type file and insert them in multiple element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I manage to generate the thumbnail via the script below

```js
$('input#fileupload').on('change', function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    var name = this.files.item(i).name;

    fr.onload = function(e) {
      $('#thumbs ul').append('<li><img src="' + e.target.result + '"><span>' + name[i] + '</span></li>');
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
  }
});
```

But unable to insert the file name into the appended `<li></li>` element

Comment: Because I need to grab each of the attached image from the file input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `files.item(i).name` which is invalid. You instead need to access the `files` array by index, then get the `name` property.

Also note that when you append the variable in to the `span`, you can use `name` directly, not `name[i]`.

Finally, you'll need to use a closure to maintain the scope of the current `file` when in the `onload` event handler. Try this:

```js
$('input#fileupload').on('change', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    (function(file) {
      var name = file.name;
      var fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = function(e) {
        $('#thumbs ul').append('<li><img src="' + e.target.result + '"><span>' + name + '</span></li>');
      };
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    })(this.files[i])
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileupload" multiple="true" />

<div id="thumbs">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Err, it does add the file name, but when multiple files has been attached, all the file name become the same.

Comment: You're right - I updated the answer to fix that. Basically you'll need a closure to keep the scope of the loop within the `onload` event handler

Comment: Thanks Rory, you rock! It works now! I'm cracking my head for 2 days and you got it fixed in 3 minutes.  I can see the level difference gap here.